# Dependency Injection for DbContext from Repository Layer in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Normal asp.net core api example applications inject Derived class of `DbContext` from Controller Constructor
 `private readonly ApplicationContext context;
        public EmployeeController(ApplicationContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }` . here Controller directly communicates with EF. 
But I would like to create thin Controllers. ***Controller -> service layer -> repository Layer.***

- Service Layer will do Business Logics and bind Business Object to Transfer Object.
- Repository Layer Only Depend on DB Context.

So Controller Constructor no need to Inject Db Context. How to Inject DBContext only with Repository. 
Another Q is, is the way right to develop Rest Services? or shall we follow the same way (Controller to EF)?

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify your question (and fix the formatting:D ).  Are you having troubles injecting something other than ApplicationContext?

Comment: I have updated. I am just Inject **ApplicationContext**.  I dont want to inject  form controller. I am trying to Inject From  Repository Layer.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the `ApplicationDBContext` in the Services section of Startup.CS.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

then you can include it in your repository constructor

```
public AppRepository(ApplicationContext context)
{
     this.context = context;
}
```

Above answer assumes that the repository class is part of your Web API project.